# pass json data to aspx webmethod page error: "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 is not supported for deserialization of an array"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, webmethod

I Want Pass json Object to WebMethod in aspx page

here's my jquery and WebMethod

```
$("#button-login").bind({
        Click: accountRegister
    });



function accountRegister(e) {

    var dataObj = $("#login input[type]").serializeArray();
    var obj = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Checkout.aspx/login",
        data: obj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",

        beforSend: function () {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
            $(this).after(waitObj);
        },

        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            alert("success");
            $("#checkout").slideUp("slow");
            $("#payment-address").slideDown("slow");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
         //alert(msg);
        },
        complete: function (jqxhr,status) {
            alert("Type:" + $.type(jqxhr) + "\n Respons text: " + jqxhr.responseText + "\n status: " + status);

            $(this).attr("disabled", "false");
            $(".wait").remove();

        },
    });
}
```

my checkout.cs file

```
  namespace Ahooratech
    {

        public partial class Checkout : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            [WebMethod]
            public static string login(string obj)
            { return "{data:data}";}

    }
```

i get this Errro:

> Respons text: {"Message":"Type
>   \u0027****System.Collections.Generic.*IDictionary*`2****[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 **is not supported for
>   *deserialization* of an array**.",
>
> "StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList
>   list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean
>   throwOnError, IList\u0026 convertedList)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext
>   context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

**EDIT: Error represent a Type castiny but where is this casting? (I think there is a implicit type casting in JQuery)**

EDITE: this is my obj Content in json form which send to server

```
"[{"name":"userName","value":"admin"},{"name":"password","value":"admin_"}]"
```

I figured This lines of accountRegister() to this:

var obj = JSON.Stringify(**{data:dataObj}**);

and in WebMethod modify to this:

public static string void login(Object **data**)
{

}

and it works!

but i how can id Deserilize **data**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can not pass any array to a `WebMethod` as root object. You have to encapsulate data with a javascript object. Also your root object keys should match parameters of `WebMethod`.

If you want to pass an array, you can use that format.

```
JSON.stringfy({myArray: [1,2,3]})
```

In this case; your `WebMethod` signature should be like

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MethodName(IEnumerable<object> myArray);
```

The inner type of enumeration can be any type but parameter name should match with parameter name of json object.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you don't get an error when changing the paramater of the login function to type object.

Actually i would pass all parameters separately to the webmethod and not as one object.

Comment: i think there is a type casting. the error raise when the post perform by ajax method

Answer (score 0):

I Decorate my ajax method to this

```
 function accountRegister(e) {


    var data = $("#login input[type]").serializeArray();

    var str="[";
    $.each(data, function(index , value)
    {
        str += '{' + '"name"' + ":" + "\"" + value.name + "\"" + ', ' + '"value"' + ":" + "\"" + value.value + "\"" + '},';


    });
    // remove last char ","
    data = str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
   data += "]";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Checkout.aspx/login",
        data: JSON.stringify({ myData: data }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
       // converts: {               "html text": function(data) { return $(data);}},
        //dataFilter: function(data,dataType) {           if(dataType == "json")        {    var dataFilter = $.parseJSON(data);        return data;              }              else return data;            },
        beforSend: function () {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
            $(this).after(waitObj);
        },

        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            alert("success");
          // $("#checkout").slideUp("slow");
           // $("#payment-address").slideDown("slow");
        },
```

and web method to this

```
public  class nameVal
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static string login(object myData)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<nameVal> myformElement = js.Deserialize<List<nameVal>>(myData.ToString());

        return "";

    }
```